# Declaration of exchanges and queues in Akka AMQP

Tags: scala, amqp, akka

Maybe I'm just not seeing it, but is there a way to declare exchanges and queues in Akka AMQP (Scala)?

Edit: I can see how to declare exchanges now, but how to declare queues?

Answer (score 0):

The queue is created when you create a new consumer. For example, if you want to create a queue named "foobar" for use in a direct exchange, you will create your consumer as

```
val consumer = AMQP.newConsumer(connection, ConsumerParameters("foobar", ...), ...)
```